# Redirection using htaccess file from one domain to another

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with the name of "http://wowriters.com/" but that website is also accessable from "http://beeelkazi33813.ipage.com/writers/".

I want that my "http://wowriters.com/" website should not be accessible from "http://beeelkazi33813.ipage.com/writers/".

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is not any directory

Comment: /writers/ directory is pointing on "wowriters.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your site root directory (`/writers/`), add this block rule for 2nd domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =beeelkazi33813.ipage.com
RewriteRule .* http://wowriters.com/$0 [L,R=301,NE]
```